# Menu Item in AHK

Tags: autohotkey

I'm switching from keyboard maestro and mac, to AHK and Windows.

I'd like to choose a menu item in Thunderbird, say,

```
"Message>Move to>me@email.com>Archive".
```

Or I'd like to choose bookmark "2checkvist" in Chrome.

How do I create hotkeys to menu items? And how do I keep them to only that program, so that alt+t in chrome can do one thing, while alt+t in thunderbird does another thing?

Comment: The latter question should be easy to answer by reading the official documentation: `#ifWinActive`. The former - possibly as well.

Answer (score 0):

As Jan Dvorak says, look at `ifWinActive` [in the docs](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfWinActive.htm) (I should get a point for posting the link to docs, you know).

Then you can use `send` with the alt key, something like this (you have to expiriment).

```
ifwinexist thunderbird
{
    winactivate thunderbird
    send !m ;message menu
    send m ;move to (if you have more m-commands, then you have to send this more than once till you get to it)
   send something  ;here put keys until you get to your account
    send a  ;archive
}
```

Basically, you want ahk to use the alt menu keys.  Everyone's interface differs a little depending on your addons and version. In your main interface, hold down the alt key and look at your menu bar.  You will see that little underlines appear under certain letters.  This is your "alt" key command.  Now, figure out the sequence.  You only need to push alt once to open the "alt thread" - now navigate manually through the menus using your keyboard.  Now translate that sequence into autohotkey `send` commands.

You might also have to use `activateWindow` to assure your alt key will take correctly.

Comment: ^#o::
ifwinactive Notepad++
{
    send !l
    send t
   send {Down}  ;here put keys until you get to your account
    send {Enter}  ;latex
}

Did not work, see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5uEvt2fUHew

Comment: Don't just use the code I posted - it's only an example.  I edite my answer to explain further.

Comment: Thanks, but I knew about the alt key commands, and I figured out the sequence to be !l,t,down,enter. Thus I posted the code

^#o:: 

ifwinactive Notepad++ 

{ 

    send !l 

    send t 

    send {Down} 

    send {Enter}

}

return

But it did not work. I have no idea where I am doing it wrong.

Comment: Try putting `sleep, 1000` in between the `send` commands so you can see the actual menus opening.  Then you can see what is happening.  In fact, adding the `sleep` between some of the commands might help it some.

Comment: Now I have written this. I think it should work, but it doesn't. When I eliminated Ifwinexist, it worked. I've also tried using ifwinactive instead of ifwinexist.
 ^#o::
 Ifwinexist, notepad++
  send, !l
  sleep, 1000
  send, t 
  sleep, 1000
  send, {Down} 
  sleep, 1000
  send, {Enter}
 else
  run, notepad++
 return

Comment: Does that sequence work fine when you do it yourself, manually, without the script?  And, when you watch the script, how far does it get before it fails?  Where does it miss?

Comment: If you can find the window with `ifwinexist`, then you need to activate the window before you can use the alt-sequence on it.

Comment: Thanks BGM, i forgot the winactivate. Also, sleep made it work.